# How can I change serenity-bdd log settings in maven

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, serenity-bdd

Were using serenity-bdd, and log analysis is important. But there is a lot of spam in the logging:

Serenety uses a lot of asci art in there logging witch is in my case waste of space and giving a lot of noice:

```
end2endtests    |  _____ _____ ____ _____   ____ _____  _    ____ _____ _____ ____  
end2endtests    | |_   _| ____/ ___|_   _| / ___|_   _|/ \  |  _ \_   _| ____|  _ \ 
end2endtests    |   | | |  _| \___ \ | |   \___ \ | | / _ \ | |_) || | |  _| | | | |
end2endtests    |   | | | |___ ___) || |    ___) || |/ ___ \|  _ < | | | |___| |_| |
end2endtests    |   |_| |_____|____/ |_|   |____/ |_/_/   \_\_| \_\|_| |_____|____/ 
end2endtests    |                                                                   
end2endtests    |
```

And then on the end we get:

```
end2endtests    |         __    _____ _____ ____ _____   ____   _    ____  ____  _____ ____  
end2endtests    |   _     \ \  |_   _| ____/ ___|_   _| |  _ \ / \  / ___|/ ___|| ____|  _ \ 
end2endtests    |  (_)_____| |   | | |  _| \___ \ | |   | |_) / _ \ \___ \\___ \|  _| | | | |
end2endtests    |   _|_____| |   | | | |___ ___) || |   |  __/ ___ \ ___) |___) | |___| |_| |
end2endtests    |  (_)     | |   |_| |_____|____/ |_|   |_| /_/   \_\____/|____/|_____|____/ 
end2endtests    |         /_/                                                                
end2endtests    | 
end2endtests    | TEST PASSED
```

We do this in our Jenkins server trough a Maven command, I realy would like to reduce this noice so we have a bit less logging and sutch. I been googeling for it but havent found a clear cut answer that gave me the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `-Dserenity.console.headings=minimal` or `-Dserenity.console.headings=normal` in command line.

Or use

```
System.SetProperty("serenity.console.headings", "normal");
```

See below for more details

http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below properties in serenity.properties file to turn off logging in reporting. (Serenity model/core version: 2.2.5)

serenity.console.headings=none to turn off the TEST STARTED banner and serenity.console.banner=none to turn off the SERENITY BDD banner.

Reference:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-model/latest/net/thucydides/core/ThucydidesSystemProperty.html